# Doctrine: many-to-many, self-referencing BUT using yaml mapping file

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I need to create a relationship between objects where an object can have parents and child of the same type.

Think at something like a categories tree where a category can have a parent category (or more than one parent category) and can also have a child category (or more than one child categories).

So, [Doctrine explains how to do this](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/association-mapping.html#many-to-many-self-referencing) but the example uses the `annotations`.

But in my project I'm using the `yaml` files to describe the mappings and I don't know how to transform the Doctrine's examples into `yaml`.

Can anyone help me, please?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, this is the solution:

```
manyToMany:
    parentDependencies:
        targetEntity: SerendipityHQ\Bundle\QueuesBundle\Entity\Job
        inversedBy: childDependencies
        joinTable:
            name: queues_jobs_chains
            joinColumns:
                child_job:
                    referencedColumnName: id
            inverseJoinColumns:
                parent_job:
                    referencedColumnName: id
    childDependencies:
        targetEntity: SerendipityHQ\Bundle\QueuesBundle\Entity\Job
        mappedBy: parentDependencies
```

Answer (score 0):

I would encourage you to study the [YAML Mapping Documentation](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/reference/yaml-mapping.html#example) provided by [Doctrine](http://www.doctrine-project.org/).

Also note that you can use `orm:convert-mapping` command that doctrine offers to convert between mappings

Example:

```
php bin/console doctrine:mapping:convert --filter User yml  /path_to_yml
```

*filter is optional*

Comment: Eh eh, you linked it, but did you read it? There is no mention of a many-to-many self-referencing relation... unfortunately!

And I cannot convert mapping as this would require more work only to do the conversion (to tell Symfony to load both yaml mappings and annotations too... and I don't ever know if is possible to mix the two... o.O)...

Comment: there is no special mappings for self-referencing relation. you just use the combination manyToMany , targetEntity, joinTable, etc . Also the idea behind conversion is not to use both, but to write the mappings,  in the format you know in a separate demo project , convert and use it in the original project.

Comment: I need an example, can you provide one? Too much work to create a demo project, ecc... I think this is an example that MUST be online... So this is the right question to create one...